# Getting php to properly format jsonp response to populate div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have spent days searching for the answer to this, and I'm getting close, but I can't seem to get it to actually work.

I would like example1.com to submit a request to example2.com where example2.com processes that request and example1.com displays the output in a div without reloading the page.

Here is what I have:

example1.com (html)

```
<div class="option">
 <form id="option" action="https://example2.com/process.php" method="get">
   <div class="input">
     <div id="option">
       <div class="block">
         <div class="title">Select Option</div>
         <div class="input-resp"><span>
           <select name="cmd">
               <option name="option" value="online">Online</option>
               <option name="option" value="offline">Offline </option></span>
             </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="submit">
   <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
   </div>
 </form>
</div>
<div class="response">
  <div id=response></div>
</div>
```

example1.com (javascript)

```
$('#option').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    cache: true, // remove jsonp callback from url
    dataType: "jsonp", // use jsonp for cross domain requests
    jsonp: false, // remove jsonp timestamp from url
    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
    type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
    url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
    success: function(result) { // on success..
        $('#response').html(result); // update the DIV
    }
});
return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

Note:  For testing, I added some settings to the ajax call in attempts to remove the callback and timestamp from the URL.  When I navigate to the page directly, it works just fine without them, but fails when I attempt to navigate directly using the modified URL (with the callback and timestamp).

Ideally, I would rather not use the added settings to remove the callback, but I just don't know how to process it using php to get a response.

These are the apache access logs:

```
[09/May/2015:14:32:20 -0700] "GET /process.php?cmd=online HTTP/1.1" 200 1110  // Without callback and timestamp

[09/May/2015:14:31:16 -0700] "GET /process.php?callback=jQuery172026217079092748463_1431207074531&cmd=online&_=1431207076762 HTTP/1.1" 200 4765  // With callback and timestamp
```

So here is what I have in php to process the request.  (again, this produces some expected output in a browser when I navigate directly to the file).

example2.com/process.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

if ($_GET[cmd] == "online") {
$output = shell_exec('some server side commands');
$oparray = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $output);
$odd = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $output);
$even = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $output);
foreach ($oparray as $key => $value) {
  if (0 == $key % 2) {
    $even[] = $value;
    //echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($value).')';  //this didn't work
    $json = json_encode($value);
    $jsonp_callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : null;
    print $jsonp_callback ? "$jsonp_callback($json)" : $json;
  }
  else {
    $odd[] = $value;
    // echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($value).')';  //this didn't work
    $json = json_encode($value);
    $jsonp_callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : null;
    print $jsonp_callback ? "$jsonp_callback($json)" : $json;
  }
 }
}
```

Now I'm fairly confident that I'm not handling this properly as far as jsonp is concerned, but I can't seem to get any useful errors.  I tried adding `console.log(error);` to the error setting, and that only showed 202 success in firebug's console.

```
error: function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
```

I also tried `alert(error);` and that gave me `object Object` in the popup.

Any help in getting this working is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Content-Type` header would also need to be conditional on type of output. Also add type `OPTION` to allowed methods. Should be enough headers with that to not even need jsonp. Browsers will send a prefilight request (OPTION) if jsonp not specified and only json to see if remote domain is CORS enabled...then send the full request if OPTION returns proper headers

Comment: as for error in ajax with jsonp...jQuery API docs will tell you that error callback isn't available with jsonp. But you can inspect the actual reponse body in network tab of browser dev tools (f12)...to see exactly what you are getting back

Comment: Ok, so I tried not using jsonp so I can see what the error is.  I got statusText "error".  I also tried simply to echo the $value to see if I could simply get a response... nothing.  I did notice that I'm not getting any ResponseHeaders or RequestHeaders with any of my markups.  I'll check the actual response, and post back my results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.

example1.com (HTML) (Stayed the same)

```
<div class="option">
<form id="option" action="https://example2.com/process.php" method="get">
  <div class="input">
    <div id="option">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="title">Select Option</div>
        <div class="input-resp"><span>
        <select name="cmd">
           <option name="option" value="online">Online</option>
           <option name="option" value="offline">Offline </option></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </div>
</form>
</div>
  <div class="response">
    <div id=response></div>
  </div>
```

I added jsonpCallback setting (that's one part I was missing).  The response string should look like `peers(["string of data])` where `peers=callback`.

Here is what it looks like

example1.com (javascript)

```
$('#peers').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
  $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    cache: true, // remove jsonp callback from url
    dataType: "jsonp", // use jsonp for cross domain requests
    jsonp: "jsonp", // set callback option in url
    jsonpCallback: "peers",  /set callback for response string
    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
    type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
    url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
    success: function(result) { // on success..
        $('#response').text(result); // update the DIV
    }
  });
return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

Since jsonp modifies the url with the callback, I added a check for that in example2.com/process.php as well as properly formatting the string with the callback.

Here's what it looks like.

example2.com/process.php

```
if (isset($_GET[jsonp]) && $_GET[cmd] == "online") {
  header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTION');
  $output = shell_exec('some server side commands');
  $callback = $_GET[jsonp];
  $array = array($output);
  $json = json_encode($array);
  echo $callback.'('.$json.');';
}
```

Works like a charm.